# How can I add style to a PHP link (i.e. text-decoration: underline)?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a link on a WP blog to the author.  But when viewing the page, the link just blends in with the rest of the text. I'd like the viewers to know that the author's name is a clickable link, and if they'd like to view the author's profile, they can click that link.

So the snippet of code is:

```
<div class="postdate">
<?php the_time('l, F jS, Y') ?> by 
    <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>                        
at
<?php the_time() ?>
</div>
```

So of course I'd have to do something with the **the_author_posts_link** line.  But I'm not sure how I'd add something in there, such as style="text-decoration: underline" or something, so it's acceptable in php.  Any information or guidance in this regard would be greatly appreciated!

CLARIFICATION

Previously, the output was this:

```
Thursday, February 14th, 2013 by Jason+ at 10:05 am
```

After instituting your css snippet offered by Mr. Alien, the output was the same:

```
Thursday, February 14th, 2013 by Jason+ at 10:05 am
```

But it DID underline when I hovered over it, which is strange.  I'd like it to be underlined prior to hovering over it, which it should as far as I see the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not understanding your question but if this function `the_author_posts_link();` is returning the link, than you can do it like this

```
.postdate a {
   text-decoration: underline; /* You can use !important declaration if you are
                                  not getting the underline, perhaps something 
                                  must be overriding so... */
}
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Alien.  Thanks for taking the time to respond.  I think you have me on the right track.  Previously, the output was this: Thursday, February 14th, 2013 by Jason+ at 10:05 am ..... after instituting your css snippet, the output was the same -- Thursday, February 14th, 2013 by Jason+ at 10:05 am  -- but it DID underline when I hovered over it, which is strange.  It should be underlined without the hover.  Regardless, I think I'm on the right track now; just have to tinker with it.  Thanks again for your help, Mr. Alien!

Comment: @JasonWeber glad it helped you, and did you tried this? `.postdate a {text-decoration: underline !important;}` just be sure you have a space between underline and !important word

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, Mr. Alien!  I'm not sure what the significance of the !important is, but I see it often; I'll have to w3schools that or google it.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @JasonWeber So you missed out the comment in my answer, no issues, it is because probably something is overriding your CSS so you need to use `!important` declaration :)

Comment: Thanks Mr. Alien ... appreciate your help and the knowledge!